# Firebug Lite selected html element

Tags: firebug-lite

How to get the selected element on the page with Firebug Lite?
I mean xPath or DOM-chain like in lower bar in WebInspector.

For example:
**Html page**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="div_id">Text in div element</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After select div-element with Firebug Lite I want to get something like this: `html->body->div#div_id`